# How does setting baselineAligned to false improve performance in LinearLayout?

Tags: android, listview, android-lint

I was just building some UI in xml, and Lint gave me a warning and said to set android:baselineAligned to false to improve performance in ListView.

The docs for the Lint changes that added this warning say

> Layout performance: Finds LinearLayouts with weights where you should
>   set android:baselineAligned="false" for better performance, and also
>   finds cases where you have nested weights which can cause performance
>   problems.

Can somebody explain why this improves performance, specifically when weight is involved?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

By setting `android:baselineAligned="false"` , you're preventing the extra work your app's layout has to do in order to Align its children's baselines; which can obviously increase the performance. (Fewer unnecessary operations on UI => Better performance)

Comment: That part is obvious. What I was trying to get at is why is this only a performance improvement when weight is involved?

Comment: Because linearlayout only need to calculate the baseline when weights are involved. Its like a smart feature which actually can be annoying.

Comment: The term baseline comes from typography. It's the invisible line letters in text sit on. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_%28typography%29

Comment: So if it's a performance improvement, that means work that's normally done isn't being done anymore.  What are the side-effects of this?  Does the work that we're now avoiding have the capability of yielding different results?

Comment: @lhunath according to the documentation, The default is set to **true**. this forces the baseline of any UI text to align themselves with eachother. For example think about buttons,you have like two buttons with same width/height on the same line but one of them have a longer text, because of `baselineAlined="true"`, the button with longer text can end up moving around to align it's text with other buttons. For a better example, check out [this post](http://udinic.wordpress.com/tag/baselinealigned/)

Comment: Here is the visual solution! http://stackoverflow.com/a/38007282/2959200

Comment: @lhunath yes it can result in different layout as I've experienced cases where I discovered unexpectedly that the baseline is not just a property of text views but is also calculated for the layout that wraps them, example would be LinearLayout containing two RelativeLayouts each containing a Button. The RelativeLayouts calculate a baseline from their contents, you will still get the warning but the layout changes if you make the change.

Comment: Another nice article with visual explanation: https://medium.com/@pareshmayani/androiddev-tip-set-android-baselinealigned-false-on-this-element-for-better-performance-810fa3148043

Answer (score 22):

how `android:baselineAligned="false"`  help . It may not be the answer but help to get concept.

> I've just managed to get 3 items (icon, text, button) centered 
>   vertically in horizontal LinearLayout.
>
> This may seem simple, but in reality specifying
>   android:gravity="center_vertical" as LinearLayout attribute is not
>   enough - icon is centered, but text and button are not. This is
>   because (presumably) text have a baseline, and centering algorithm
>   uses it instead of 'real' vertical center. But what is worse - button
>   (which comes next to text) is centered using text's baseline!
>
> Specifying android:baselineAligned="false" in LinearLayout turns this
>   off, and everything centers correctly.

Answer (score 17):

```
// Baseline alignment requires to measure widgets to obtain the
                // baseline offset (in particular for TextViews). The following
                // defeats the optimization mentioned above. Allow the child to
                // use as much space as it wants because we can shrink things
                // later (and re-measure).
                if (baselineAligned) {
                    final int freeSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                    child.measure(freeSpec, freeSpec);
                }
```

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/LinearLayout.java#L1093