# Linear Layout baselinealigned warning on android

Tags: android, performance, android-linearlayout

i am getting "Set android:baselineAligned="false" on this element for better performance" while using LinearLayout, I know its regarding performance,but i dont know exactly why it is,please clarify me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does setting baselineAligned to false improve performance in LinearLayout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319916/how-does-setting-baselinealigned-to-false-improve-performance-in-linearlayout)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> android:baselineAligned/setBaselineAligned(boolean): When set to false,
>   prevents the layout from aligning its children's baselines.

So can take example with linear layout with horizontal child views having multiple TextView with different text size or different views like button there basealignment would be different **and you cannot adjust it to have same basealignment if you set it to false**

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#setBaselineAligned(boolean))

**Update:** 
By setting android:baselineAligned="false" , you're preventing the extra work your app's layout has to do in order to Align its children's baselines; which can obviously increase the performance. (Less unnecessary operations on UI => Better performance) as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319916/how-does-setting-baselinealigned-to-false-improve-performance-in-linearlayout)

Comment: And what are the gotchas for doing this?

Answer (score 73):

If you are looking for a visual explanation like me, then you might find this useful.

When `baselineAlign` is enabled(i.e if it is set to true), then all the text in that line will be aligned to have the same baseline.

**Note:** By default, `baselineAligned` is set to `true`. (i.e. `baselineAligned=true`)

When you make `baselineAligned=false`, all it needs to do is to add new elements to the linear layout and be done with it. The app need not worry about where the baseline of other elements in the layout is.

See the image below for more clarity

[image]

Comment: This is an answer! Many answers'd be in this way!